# MS SQL split values in same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day

I have :

```
TableX
Column1
John Smith 007
Tera Name 111
Bob Eva 554
```

I need

```
TableX
Column1                              Column2
John Smith 007                         007
Tera Name 111                          111
Bob Eva 554                            554
```

I created code but not work. I think there must be join to recognise columns.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableX]
ADD Column2 varchar (50); 

UPDATE [dbo].[TableX] SET
    Column1=Column2
WHERE select SUBSTRING([Column1], PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', [Column1]
), LEN([column1]))
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number you want to extract is *always at the end*, then you can use:

```
PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Column1))
```

to get the index of the first character that is not a number, starting from the end.

So, to extract the number you can use:

```
RIGHT(Column1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Column1)) - 1)
```

Hence, the `UPDATE` will look like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TableX] 
SET Column2 = RIGHT(Column1, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(Column1)) - 1)
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/GCM38501)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming required part length = 3

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TableX] SET
column2 = RTRIM(right(column1, CHARINDEX('/', column1) +3))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.